# Setting a main window title for macOS SwiftUI app in AppKit?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, wkwebview, appkit

I have a simplistic WKWebView app that opens up a website on macOS, using SwiftUI in AppKit.
However, the app window has no title - I'm talking of the top row (with the red X to close it, etc.

How do I set a title there? I've tried looking at Main.Storyboard but am not seeing anything resembling a "title segment".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Window is created in `AppDelegate`, so you can do it as below...

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()

    // Create the window and set the content view. 
    window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.title = "Some title" // << assign title here
    ...
```

Comment: I added window.title = "the title", and now it shows. Thanks for the advice, @Asperi, marking this as solved :)

Answer (score 31):

As of MacOS 11, the window title can be set using .navigationTitle on a View. For example:

```swift
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .navigationTitle("Hello!")
    }
```

From Apple's help:

> A view’s navigation title is used to visually display the current
> navigation state of an interface. On iOS and watchOS, when a view is
> navigated to inside of a navigation view, that view’s title is
> displayed in the navigation bar. On iPadOS, the primary destination’s
> navigation title is reflected as the window’s title in the App
> Switcher. Similarly on macOS, the primary destination’s title is used
> as the window title in the titlebar, Windows menu and Mission Control.

Answer (score 0):

if You have only ONE ContentView

(that was created in AppDelegate with: window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView) as per Apple single View App..)

You can do in your ContentView:

```
private func setTitle(title: String) {
    if let ad = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate{
        ad.window.title = title
    }
}
```

(seems a bit orribile.. remember me old days of iOS 2.11, with abuse of App Delegate... story returns)